# In Java how to use AES encryption so that a static string/text will result in similar encrypted message each time?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric

I have a situation where I have to store the encrypted from of a text in an excel sheet and my java code should read that encrypted text from a excel sheet and convert it back to original text and hit the server with original plain text.
I'm trying to achieve this with AES encryption/decryption logic but I'm not able to achieve it as every time I convert the plain text into encrypted format for it to be stored in the excel sheet it results in a different encrypted string each time so I'm not able to decrypt it back to original, what I want is for a same static string/text my AES encrypted text should also be static.
I know even if my encrypted string is dynamic I can convert it back to decrypted format but for my case what I want is my encrypted text should also remain static.
How can I achieve this?

Ex. If my plain text is "This is a question" my encrypted string is different each time like below

Enter
This is a question
Encrypted Data : mFsue8JGwLcJQTiBzM0HLVvdDXKPNGsG/O7N60joH+Ozgg==
Decrypted Data : This is a question

Enter
This is a question
Encrypted Data : FdBz3cGS4NphK14Fw8Me4daM4lVzdrK47WUMSRiUVe+juQ==
Decrypted Data : This is a question

See the encrypted data's are different each time. I want that to be static

The classes which I'm using are as below (please note these are not my exact classes but they implement the same logic which I have used. These example classes may have some non used variables and methods, I have mentioned just for reference)

Method.java

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Method {

private static SecretKey key;
private final int KEY_SIZE = 128;
private final int DATA_LENGTH = 128;
private Cipher encryptionCipher;

/*
 * public void init() throws Exception { KeyGenerator keyGenerator =
 * KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); keyGenerator.init(KEY_SIZE); key =
 * keyGenerator.generateKey();
 * 
 * 
 * }
 */

// String to Key


  public static void getKeyFromPassword(String toEnc, String salt) throws
  NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException { SecretKeyFactory factory
  = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256"); KeySpec spec = new
  PBEKeySpec(toEnc.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 128); SecretKey
  originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(),"AES"); 
  key= originalKey; }
  
 
/*
 * public static void convertStringToSecretKeyto(String string) {
 * 
 * 
 * byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(string.getBytes()); byte[]
 * decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(string); key = new
 * SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
 * System.out.println(bytesEncoded); System.out.println(decodedKey);
 * 
 * }
 */

   public String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
    byte[] dataInBytes = data.getBytes();
    encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    
    encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptionCipher.doFinal(dataInBytes);
    return encode(encryptedBytes);
   }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
    byte[] dataInBytes = decode(encryptedData);
    Cipher decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

    GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(DATA_LENGTH, 
    encryptionCipher.getIV());
    decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = decryptionCipher.doFinal(dataInBytes);
    return new String(decryptedBytes);
    }

    private String encode(byte[] data) {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
    }

    private byte[] decode(String data) {
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
    } 
}
```

Main.class

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cypher {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    try {
        Method aes_encryption = new Method();
 
        
 //       aes_encryption.init();
       Method.getKeyFromPassword("Texty text","Salty salt");
        
        System.out.println("Enter");
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String s= sc.nextLine();
        String encryptedData = aes_encryption.encrypt(s);
        String decryptedData = aes_encryption.decrypt(encryptedData);
      

        System.out.println("Encrypted Data : " + encryptedData);
       System.out.println("Decrypted Data : " + decryptedData);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 65536 is a relatively low iteration count nowadays. Please make sure that you use the highest iteration count possible, or make sure your password is **really** secure.

Comment: Perhaps some comments in: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136739/aes-use-same-nonce-security-risk could help with "I want that to be static"

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an implementation issue; your issue is with the used encryption scheme.

The nonce or IV are used to randomize your ciphertext. This gives you an important property: identical plaintext will encrypt to randomized ciphertext. This is required for a cipher to be secure, as you could otherwise identify identical plaintext messages.

Now you could just fix the IV or nonce, but that means that you will leak information early: if the first blocks of plaintext are identical then those blocks will result in identical ciphertext. Instead you can use an encryption scheme where each of the ciphertext bits depend on *all* of the plaintext bits.

There are several schemes that offer this kind of property:

- biIGE mode: the bi-directional infinite garble extension mode is an encryption mode that runs both forward and then backwards. It is an odd mode that isn't used or implemented much;
- FPE modes: format preserving encryption can be used to encrypt X plaintext bits into exactly X ciphertext bits, it is mainly used for smaller plaintext messages such as credit cards (so that there aren't any additional storage requirements for encrypted credit card numbers);
- AES-SIV mode: synthetic IV mode is probably the best option, it can encrypt large(r) messages, and offers authenticity as well as the MAC / authentication tag doubles as IV. It has the drawback that it does require additional room for the synthetic IV / authentication tag. It is also a two-pass mode (all plaintext bytes are visited twice), which means that it won't be as performant as other generic modes.

There is AES-GCM-SIV for a performant option of the latter.

Of course, as indicated by others, you really want to make sure that you **need** this kind of functionality: not having messages encrypt to the same ciphertext is a rather fundamental security property of a cipher.

Comment: What you are asking is not implementation specific either, and hashing is not asked for. There should be AES-GCM-SIV implementations available, so I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here. Maybe it is that I don't provide library recommendations, but that's on purpose.

Comment: The problem was that I just yesterday tried to solve the problem to always create "similar message each time" and try to find out if I did something wrong and how to solve it better.
Therefore thanks for your input, you helped me somewhat as well.
Can you point me to information where the risk of somebody figuring out the AES-256 key if the source has 64 Bit and the nonce is constant but not known, might be calculatable?

Comment: I don't know what "the source has 64 Bit" means, or what this has to do with the question at hand. Feel free to ask your question at [crypto.se] but please try and keep things formal, include as much info as possible and review your question before posting.